# Let $A, B, C$ be sets, with $B \subseteq C.$ Prove that $(A \times B) \subseteq (A \times C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A, B, C$ be sets, with $B \subseteq C.$ Prove that $(A \times B) \subseteq (A \times C)$

I understand why this is true but I need help answering it in a mathematical way, not just using common sense.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $B\subseteq C$. You want to prove that $A\times B\subseteq A\times C$, so take an element $(a,b)\in A\times B$.

Since $B\subseteq C$, and since $b\in B$, we have $b\in C$. Thus $(a,b)\in A\times C$, which proves that whenever $(a,b)\in A\times B$, then also $(a,b)\in A\times C$.